# Creating greet in batch file using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, batch

I'm trying to create greeting in batch file using PowerShell but getting error

**Code:-**

```
powershell -Command $Hour = (Get-Date).Hour; Write-host "Hi"; If ($Hour -lt 12) {"Good Morning $($Env:UserName)" }; ElseIf ($Hour -gt 16) {"Good Eventing $($Env:UserName)"}; Else {"Good Afternoon $($Env:UserName)"}

pause
```

**Error I'm getting: -**

```
Good : The term 'Good' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included,
verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:60
+ ... our = (Get-Date).Hour; Write-host Hi; If ($Hour -lt 12) {Good Morning ...
+                                                              ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Good:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

ElseIf : The term 'ElseIf' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was
included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:93
+ ... i; If ($Hour -lt 12) {Good Morning $($Env:UserName) }; ElseIf ($Hour  ...
+                                                            ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (ElseIf:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Else : The term 'Else' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included,
verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:149
+ ...  ElseIf ($Hour -gt 16) {Good Eventing $($Env:UserName)}; Else {Good A ...
+                                                              ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Else:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: Why the batch file at all? Just curious. Why not just do this in your profile, or your Prompt function, or as a script to call vs on a command line, and avoid all the quoting gymnastics? With code in your profile, it will do this for each session. With the code in your profile prompt function, it will execute on each prompt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the command(s) inside quotes. Remove semicolon between/before `elseif` and `else`. Your command should be like below

```
powershell -Command "$Hour = (Get-Date).Hour; Write-host 'Hi'; If ($Hour -lt 12) {'Good Morning $($Env:UserName)' } ElseIf ($Hour -gt 16) {'Good Eventing $($Env:UserName)'} Else {'Good Afternoon $($Env:UserName)'}"
pause
```

Comment: Still getting same error

Comment: @SurajKumar See edit on the command.